# Making a model persistent in the controller using doctrine2 or making the model persistent it self

Tags: php, model-view-controller, doctrine-orm

Hello I'm new in doctrine and I don't know what to do in the following situation:

I have a controller which create a new model object "Ad". Who has the responsability of making that object persistent in the DB?. The controller because it created it? or the model it self?

Acording to MVC, the model should be the only one who deals with the DB, so I guess I have to create a method call "persist" or create an interface called model which will have this method and inject the entity manager in the constructor of every model instead of making the object persistent using the entity manager in the controller.

PD: I don't want to use any framework like Zend, CI etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "model" is a layer, not a file or class that deals with persistence. Persistence belongs in there, but together with your Domain Objects, Services, Factories and whatever else your application needs.

The controllers (and views) are part of the presentation layer and as such should only be responsible for tasks regarding that.

If you are implementing domain objects then it is usually a good choice to use the [data mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern to handle persistence. If you set it up that way, then the objects themselves don't need to know anything at all about if and how they are persisted. This makes your code confirm to the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles and makes it testable.

Now you could work with your data mappers and domain objects in your controller, but a better solution for most applications is a service layer. It will allow you to reuse your service methods in multiple controllers and keep your codebase [DRY](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself). This is especially helpful if you have multiple endpoints to access your application (think normal website, admin area, API's, etc...).

A service layer class could look like this for example:

```
namespace MyApp\Models;

class OrderService
{
    public function getOrders($limit=null, $offset=null)
    {
        $orders = new OrderCollection;
        $orders->setLimit($limit);
        $orders->setOffset($offset);

        $orderCollectionMapper = new OrderCollectionMapper;
        $orderCollectionMapper->populate($orders);

        return $orders;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The controller. When your model is validated/ready to save.

Comment: Is there any reason why? because the controller created the object so it's responsible of saving it?

Comment: Your controller can know only what it would like to do with the given model.